# how to upload multiple infopath forms in single document library in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have 5 different infopath forms.on sharepoint site , i want to upload them in single document library. But when i am going to do this it is overwriting existing form. What i have to do. Is that possible to upload all 5 forms in single Document library ? I do not want to create 5 different Document libraries for 5 forms . please guide....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it would be to rename the each form and use unique name. Uploading the form with same name would result in overwriting the existing one.

In case you are submitting form directly from InfoPath then you need to change your Main Submit method. It allows you to define a name form will get as submitted. Combine it with something unique e.g. today() or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If while publishing it is overwriting then you can publish the form as a Content Type.